# save output from terminal to file in docker run session

Tags: docker

I run docker container using the command

```
docker run -t -i -v C:/Work -w=/home/work [docker_image] python simulation.py
```

Then I would like to save the output of the terminal to the log file within the /work folder. I tried

```
docker run -t -i -v C:/Work -w=/home/work [docker_image] python simulation.py > log.txt
```

but it only produces an empty log file. What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

After the container is started you could get it's logs with the following command

```
docker container logs -f CONTAINER_ID >> log.txt
```

For more info check
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/